# Methods for fitting base cabinets on top of carpet

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, carpet

I am wanting to fit some kitchen-style base cabinets for storage in one of my rooms, however this room has carpetted floor.

I was thinking about buying/building actual kitchen cabinets as these seem to be fit for my purpose, and I have see that there a few different styles of base.

I was wondering which may be best suited/easiest to use on a carpeted floor?

**Notch-style kickboard**

[image]

This seems to be popular, notching out the kickboard area from a large sheet - Of course there will be a strecher piece between both sides to give a face to the base.

It seems that this may be a good option for the carpet due to the pressure being exerted on the perimeter of the cabinet that would squish down the carpet.

Concerns - What if the carpet doesn't settle uniformally and there is tilt in one or two axes?

**Cabinet feet pegs**

[image]

These pegs are just attached to the bottom of a box and would seem to provide even more pressure on the carpet than the above example.

Concerns - I understand these legs to be somewhat fiddly to change once installed...

**Plinth**

[image]

This would be used with a box on top of course, and may be somewhat more complicated than the legs to install initially as this must be levelled first, or may place and then level the cabinet on top with shims etc.

Questions...

1. Are there other options I am not aware of?
2. Which of the above would be best suited for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put down a sheet of 1/4" hardboard or underlayment ply covering the footprint of the cabinets if you want to be nice to the carpet while leaving it in place.

They do make "carpet protectors" with many spikes to provide support without crushing the carpet (the spikes poke through the carpet pile to the floor for support) that would work with the adjustable foot option. If not too cheaply made those might actually work.

This sort of thing:

[image: Carpet spiked protector image from maisonandwhite.com]

Otherwise get some tack strips and cut the carpet so the cabinets sit on the floor. That's for the "this is a permanent installation" approach.

*Me, I'd just rip out the carpet (not a fan of the stuff.)*

Comment: If the OP goes for the first option, which all are good, I would , myself use a thicker hardboard or underlayment, since I believe, depending on how the cabinets will be used, will feel a little "squishy" under the thinner material,. If they will only be used for storage and not a workspace, the thinner will work.

Comment: Ah great, thanks for the insights! Given that it is a newly built house and I'm not 100% on the layout for these units... I'm edging on the side of laying a sheet of ply/mdf down.